# SMTP-Docker not sending emails, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: email, docker, centos-7, smtp

Please bear with me, as I only started out with Docker a couple fo days ago. I created a brand new VM with CentOS 7 in our ESXi server. Setup Docker and Portainer with no issues.

I wanted to create a simple and fast local SMTP server for some of our devices and services inside the LAN to send email messages, so I pulled the **namshi/smtp** image and created a container and mapped a random port (32768) to port 25 in the container.

The developer states:

> **As SMTP Server**
>   You don't need to specify any environment variable to
>   get this up.

So I thought there's nothing else to configure. However, I cannot send email messages. None of my devices or services are able to send emails through the SMTP docker container. These are all external, non-dockerized clients.
Am I missing something here? is it not supposed to work like this?

- My Docker VM is at **192.168.1.228**
- The smtp container is in the bridge network at **172.17.0.3**
- The container has the TCP port **32768** mapped to port **25**

I've tried sending out email and using **192.168.1.228** as the server with **32768** as the SMTP port.  No authentication and no SSL/TLS. All of the apps report an unspecified error.
For good measure I also opened the port **32768** in the CentOS firewall but the problem persist.

What am I missing here?

Logs report the following while trying to send email from a client at **192.168.1.215** (*admin@test* is the FROM address and *my.email@domain.com* is the placeholder for my personal email I used to receive the test messages)

```
281 LOG: smtp_connection MAIN,
281   SMTP connection from (localhost) [192.168.1.215] closed by QUIT,
282 LOG: host_lookup_failed MAIN,
282   no host name found for IP address 192.168.1.215,
282 LOG: MAIN REJECT,
282   H=(localhost) [192.168.1.215] F=<admin@test> rejected RCPT <my.email@domain.com>: relay not permitted,
282 LOG: lost_incoming_connection MAIN,
282   unexpected disconnection while reading SMTP command from (localhost) [192.168.1.215] D=0s,
286 LOG: host_lookup_failed MAIN,
286   no host name found for IP address 192.168.1.215
```